# The 'getRow()' method is only allowed on scroll cursors SQLException error

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby, embedded-database

I am trying to populate my JTable from my embedded database that I have set up in Netbeans.

My database contains 3 rows and 3 columns that I'd like to insert into a JTable, and make the table visible in my GUI application.

However, I am getting a java.sql.SQLException error as the title says above and my table will not turn visible in my GUI application.

Here's is my code:

```
public void FillTable(JTable table, String Query)
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:STOCK_CONTROL");
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(Query);

        //Remove previously added rows
        while (table.getRowCount() > 0)
        {
            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(0);
        }

        int columns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

        while (rs.next())
        {
            Object[] row = new Object[columns];

            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {
                row[i - 1] = rs.getObject(i);
            }
            //The error is being generated here at 'rs.getRow()'
            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).insertRow(rs.getRow() - 1, row);
        }

        rs.close();
        stat.close();
        conn.close();         
    }
    catch (InstantiationException |
            IllegalAccessException |
            ClassNotFoundException |
            SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I then create my table and call the method as above:

```
JTable tigerTable = new JTable();

FillTable(tigerTable, "SELECT * FROM TIGER_INFO");
```

I've tried to find information as to why this error is being caused, but to no avail.

My question is, how do I correctly populate my JTable from my embedded database, whilst also straying away from this unknown error I have come about?

What does this error exactly mean? I'm unsure what a 'scroll cursor' is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented in [`ResultSet.getRow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow--):

> **Note:** Support for the `getRow` method is optional for `ResultSet`s with a result set type of `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`
>   [..]
>
> Throws:
>   [..]
>   `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` - if the JDBC driver does not support this method

You either need to ask for a scrollable cursor using

```
conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

Or - probably better - keep track of the row number yourself instead of using `ResultSet.getRow()`. For example:

```
int rowIdx = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    Object[] row = new Object[columns];
    // ...

    ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).insertRow(rowIdx++, row);
}
```

It is been a while since I have done anything with swing, but it might even be simpler to just remove existing rows from the table model and call `addRow`.